Alter PostgreSQL table using create_table
I have an application that is distributed in a deb package.
The app uses a certain database structure in PostgreSQL database that may change for different versions of the app. As a result, I would like to ensure the appropriate structure for a certain version exists by running a sql script from the postint script (this question is related).
Minimal example:



Version
Full SQL
Incremental SQL




1.0.0
create table table_app (value1 text)
--


1.1.0
create table table_app (value1 text, value2 text)
alter table table_app add column value2 text


1.2.0
create table table_app (value1 text, value2 text, value3 text)
alter table table_app add column value3 text



I can create a sql script like this to be called from the postinst script and have it updated in every version release that implies database changes:
create table if not exists table_app (value1 text);
alter table table_app add column if not exists value2 text;
alter table table_app add column if not exists value2 text;

However, this will get messy if i have to include many incremental changes.
Ideally, postgresql function create_table would handle the creation of additional columns if the table exists but there is a conflict in the column structure. AFAIK, create_table does not support this.
Is there a way to create an SQL script that handles this kind of updates without the need of including the changes incrementally one by one?

Short answer: no. Just run the relevant upgrade scripts in turn: 1.0=>1.1, 1.1=>1.2, 1.2=>1,3 etc

Use Sqitch. Between it's concepts of targets and plans you can shape an upgrade path for each app version.
